# Squaring user inputs in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, user-input, mars-simulator

I have a program in which I need to take 2 keyboard-input integers from a user determine if they are valid (both inputs are the same number, and not equal to 0).  If all these criteria are met, the program enters a loop where it calculates and saves x^2 into register $s3.

I know for a fact that everything other than the portions where I assign user data to the variables works perfectly fine.  The issue is that when I add the blocks found underneath *.text* the program seems to not function after inputting the inputs.  When I run the program it gives no indication of errors and the console always returns "execution completed successfully".

My guess is there's something wrong with the saving operations, but I'm not familiar enough to understand what could be wrong with them (if that is where the problem lies).

Below is what I have:

```
    .data
arg:    .word   0
arg2:   .word   0   


    .text
li $v0, 5      #getting arg1 from user
syscall
la $t0, arg
sw $v0, 0($t0)
    
li $v0, 5      #getting arg2 from user
syscall
la $t1, arg2
sw $v0, 0($t1)
    
    .globl main
main:   
    la  $t1, arg    
    la      $t2, arg2       
    lw  $s1, 0($t1)     
    lw  $t1, 0($t1)     
                 
    addi    $s3, $zero, 0   
    beqz    $t1, fin
    bne     $t1, $t2, fin   #added in with part 2
fori:
    add $s3, $s3, $s1   
    addi    $t1, $t1, -1
    bnez    $t1, fori       
fin:
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: I think in MARS, execution starts at the `main` label.  Other code before that inside the `.text` section won't ever execute if you don't jump / call to it.  Seems like you should just put your `main` label at the top of the text section, since that's where you want execution to begin.  Single-step with MARS's debugger to see what happens; that's why it has one built-in to the IDE.

Comment: After running it through the step-by-step, MARS seems to do everything right but then seems to hit "bne $t1, $t2, fin" and completely avoid the loop.   I still don't understand how this can happen as the program does run through the lines "la $t1, arg" & "la $t2, arg2"; so as far as i'm aware, the values should be overwritten with the same int.

Comment: Even after changing the arg2 into arg so they have to be the same thing regardless of what i type in, the registers still come up as $t1 = a, $t2 = 10010014.  Is there any reason why you think $t2 could come out to something like that?

Comment: At that point `$t2` still holds an address (of `arg2`), and `$t1` holds the value loaded from `arg` with `lw  $t1, 0($t1)`.  Look at register values in the debugger.  The addresses are guaranteed to be different because there's a `.word 0` between the labels, so if that's what you meant to compare, it makes no sense to do a runtime check on them.

Comment: Well the idea is that arg & arg2 are given default values that get overwritten with what the user inputs.  I tried ```arg: arg2: .word 0``` and from what I could tell that didn't change the values of $t1 & $t2 from before.  I'm guessing what you're getting at here is that I'm initializing to the default values rather than my user-initialized values, but my question then is how would i go about that?

Comment: No, I'm saying that there's a difference between and address and the value stored at that address.  Look carefully at your `la` and `lw` instructions at the top of `main`, and which registers you're putting addresses into and then which registers you're loading into.  You load the same value twice, into two different registers, and leave the address in `$t2` unused.  Again, single-step your code in the debugger and look at register value.

Comment: Thanks, it took a bit of trouble but I added ```lw $t2, 0($t2)``` to the end of that block and everything worked out as it should.

Comment: FYI, in MARS execution starts at `.text`+0 unless the option to use `main` for the entry point is selected, but it defaults to unselected and no `main` symbol is then needed (there's also no caller of `main`, so `main` cannot "return"). QtSpim has a (default) "_start" that calls `main`, so that symbol is necessary there (and `main` can "return").  (Best common practice is to put `main` at very start of text, and use syscall #10 to exit from `main`; that bypasses these differences.)  (QtSpim also gives missing `main` as a runtime error, when it should be build time error!)

Comment: Thanks, i've been having a bit of trouble with the differences between high-level languages and assembly.